Can I lock a text field to only 3 possible letters/numbers
I want a text field where users can write only 1, X or 2 (like a bet). Only one of them, so limited to one character and only these three options. Also the X should be capitalized and not a small x.
Thanks in advance
Do not know what to try :/

That sounds like a job for radio/button/dropdown, but if you insist using an input, here's a solution


<input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^12X]/g, '')" maxlength="1" />



As a bonus, here's a more "user friendly" approach that automatically convers small x into X and replace the user input right away without requiring user to delete the previous one first.


<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/.*([12X]).*|.*/g, '$1')" />




Why on earth didn't I just make a radio button? OMG.. Thanks mate!

Might just be my insufficient skills :) I use joomla .. not sure why, but this one didn't work as well. <input class="vm_1x2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/.*([12X]).*|.*/g, '$1')" id="bet" name="bet1x2['.$row->id.']" placeholder="1X2" value="'.$row->bet.'" title="1X2">. Think it can't figure out when it's php and when it's html.

Not sure what template syntax it is. If it is PHP, it should be something similar to name="bet1x2['<?= $row->id ?>']"> etc. However, you should consider using radio buttons to handle situations like this if it is an option.



<input
   type="text"
   pattern="^(1|X|2)$"
/>




Note that if it is a lottery it is sometimes not good
Because this restriction is on the client side and therefore visible to the client!

I'll try it later when I'm at the computer. But they know it's the only possible answers. But sometimes they by mistake write 3 fx or a small x.

This will not work until user clicks an <input type="submit">


About the Problem
So you want text field with max-length of 1 and user can only input either 1 , X ,2.


Approach

first create a input field and with attribute maxlength="1" will limit its length.

<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="validate(this)">

// Now we have to validate the input it must be from required values i.e either 1,X,or 2 so that thing will be handled by validate function.

function validate(input) {
   const validchar = ['1', 'X', '2'];
        
   if (!validchar.includes(input.value)) {
      input.value = '';
   }
 }



this function is used to check the userinput belongs to validchar array or not.
if value is not matched then this will make it empty.


